# Creación de tablas para inventario de software

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE software(
idsoft int,             /*identificacion del software*/
serialsoft varchar(30) not null, /*numero de serial de software*/
nomcomesoft  varchar(30) not null, /*nombre comercial*/
empresoft text not null,               /*nombre de la empresa que desarrollo el software*/
tiposoft text not null,          /* el tipo de software*/
versoft varchar(25),          /*la version del software*/
constraint pk_software primary key(idsoft),
);

CREATE TABLE ubicacion(
idubi int,
idnumubi int ,       /*en donde esta ubicado*/
pabellon int not null , 
salon int not null,
constraint pk_ubicacion primary key(idubi)
);
```

En esta base de datos cada programa creado tiene un id que está determinado por `idsoft`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para crear una tabla donde diga cuales son los *software* que están instalados en `idubi`?

Comment: La tabla no te va decir nada, para eso requieres la consulta

Comment: Podrias explicar mejor que queres lograr? no se entiende tu pregunta...

Comment: Quiero crear una tabla donde diga cual son los software que estan en la una ubicacion determinada por idubi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En *bases de datos*, este tipo de información se representa con una *relación de muchos a muchos*, pues un *software* puede estar instalado en muchos equipos (ubicaciones en tu modelo) y un equipo puede tener instalados muchos *software*'s.

Esta relación se representa creando otra tabla, que tiene una relación de uno a muchos con cada una de las tablas que ya tienes, por ejemplo, un diagrama de un modelo de colegio, podría representar esta relación así:

[image: Relación de muchos a muchos]

En este caso, la tabla Asignación es la relación de muchos a muchos entre estudiantes y cursos. Un estudiante puede llevar muchos cursos y un curso puede *ser cursado* por muchos estudiantes.

En tu caso particular, una tabla básica para representarla podría ser esta:

```
create table ubicacion_software (
    idubisoft   int not null
  , idubi       int not null
  , idsoft      int not null
  , constraint pk_ubicacion_software primary key(idubisoft)
  , constraint fk_ubisoft_ubicacion foreign key (idubi) references ubicacion (idubi)
  , constraint fk_ubisoft_software foreign key (idsoft) references software (idsoft)
);
```

Dicho esto, hay *mucha tela que cortar*, y diferentes escuelas de pensamiento te orientarán en diferentes direcciones, trataré de mencionar las que, a mi criterio, son más importantes:

- **Llave primaria**: puedes tener una llave primaria independiente, totalmente artificial (como en mi ejemplo), o puedes tener una llave primaria compuesta por los id's de las dos tablas que relacionas, en este caso `idubi, idsoft`.

  - Duplicidad de entradas: Si tienes una llave primaria independiente, debes decidir si permitirás entradas duplicadas en la tabla, lo cual tiene componentes prácticos, como si puede un software estar instalado dos veces en un mismo equipo, y componentes *filosóficos* que están fuera del alcance de esta respuesta.

    Lo importante es, si decides que no quieres entradas duplicadas, crear una regla de integridad que garantice que se cumplirá esta regla, por ejemplo, un *constraint* `unique` sobre `idubi, idsoft`.
  - Si tienes una llave primaria compuesta por ambos campos, de entrada has decidido que no pueden haber entradas duplicadas pues, por regla, la llave primaria debe ser única.
- En el modelo más simple, cuando un equipo tiene instalado un software existe un registro en la tabla que relaciona equipo y software y cuando no lo tiene instalado no existe el registro.  En otras palabras, cuando el software se instala, se hace un insert en la tabla y cuando se desinstala se hace un delete.
- Puedes almacenar información adicional en la tabla, como la fecha de instalación, o el tipo de licencia (por ejemplo, si ya fue comprada o es una licencia de evaluación) para el caso del software comercial. Puedes almacenar en esta tabla cualquier otro dato que pueda resultar relevante en tu modelo para la entrada, como el técnico y la fecha en que hizo la instalación, la última vez que se solicitó soporte, etc.
- Podrías tener un modelo también donde, para el software que se ha desinstalado, dejes el registro, pero tienes un campo que indica si actualmente está instalado o no en la tabla.